# Apache error when executing Python cgi

Tags: python, apache, cgi, internal-server-error

Hi I have wrote a script for a webpage in python. However when I run it I seem to get this error

```
/usr/bin/env: python\r: No such file or directory
Premature end of script headers: users.cgi
```

I'm not sure what is causing it, so far I have:

- A Shebang which is #!/usr/bin/env python
- I also have other scripts that execute fine on the same server in the folder.
- I have no syntax errors in the code (I've used IDLE to check)
- The file also has 755 permissions and is owned by www-data

Could someone help me or point me in the right direction. I can't work out what is going wrong. There is very little in the apache error log. Your help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You've uploaded the file with DOS/Windows line endings. UNIX script executables have to be saved with UNIX line endings.

Comment: I thought that might have happened is that what the /r was? How do I change this so that it will work?

Comment: Right, that's what the `\r` is — it's part of the DOS/Windows line endings. (You're lucky that `env` outputs it this way; in some situations, it'll show up as a literal carriage return, which is much more confusing.) Check your text editor settings for how to fix it, or run `dos2unix` on the server.

Comment: If you are using a text editor to write your scripts, I recommend notepad ++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as it is developer oriented.